# Rounded corner effect being copied when merging with shapebuilder tool

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, cs6

I am using illustrator CS6 and I am making a rectangle with a rounded corner. What I have done is make 2 rectangles but have one with rounded corners through effect>styalize>rounded corners. I then used the shapebuilder tool to merge the two shapes together. Once merged, the rounded corner effect however gets copied to the other rectangle so then all 4 corners are rounded. Is there a way to stop this?

I noticed that when I use the pre-made rounded rectangle and merge that with another rectangle it doesn't seem to have the same problem but ideally I would like to have more control over the rounding of the corners.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the rounding effect. Apply Object > Expand Appearance before trying Shape Builder (or Unite).